# Any reason why Oracle limits BLOB size to 4000 bytes when using sequence?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, blob

I have a weird situation. I am using Oracle and ADO.NET (Visual Studio Dataset). I have a table which includes a BLOB field. Also, I have a sequence for the ID of that table. In ADO.NET, I have a tableAdapter of this table. In the insert query, I wanted it to generate the ID itself so I wrote `MYSEQ.NEXTVAL` in the insert (Where :ID should be). It works fine.

But, the thing is, when I use sequence inside the query, the BLOB is inserted wrong. No matter what the size is, it inserts 4000 bytes. This is really weird. And, when I don't use the sequence in the insert query, it is fine. I get the NextID with another query and give the outcome to the ID field of insert. It works fine. But I just wonder the reason of it. It looks really stupid.

I am not sure the name is ADO.NET. I am talking about tableadapters and dataset which I use in Visual Studio. Sorry if I am wrong.

```
INSERT INTO IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK
                     (ID, BASVURUID, EVRAK, DOSYAADI, TARIH, TANIM)
       VALUES        (:ID, :BASVURUID, :EVRAK, :DOSYAADI, :TARIH, :TANIM)
```

EVRAK is the file. It is the working code. Below is the not-working code.

```
INSERT INTO IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK
                     (ID, BASVURUID, EVRAK, DOSYAADI, TARIH, TANIM)
       VALUES        (IPYYB_KOM_EVRAK_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :BASVURUID, :EVRAK, :DOSYAADI,
                      :TARIH, :TANIM)
```

this is the sequence,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "MUBIS"."IPYYB_KOM_EVRAK_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 
                MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 
                CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

This is the table,

```
CREATE TABLE "MUBIS"."IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK"
  (
    "ID"        NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "BASVURUID" NUMBER,
    "EVRAK" BLOB,
    "DOSYAADI" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    "TARIH" DATE,
    "TANIM" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT "IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE
  )
  SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
  )
  TABLESPACE "USERS" LOB
  (
    "EVRAK"
  )
  STORE AS BASICFILE
  (
    TABLESPACE "USERS" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION NOCACHE LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  ) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MUBIS"."IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK_PK" ON "MUBIS"."IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK"
  (
    "ID"
  )
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
  )
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MUBIS"."SYS_IL0000097973C00003$$" ON "MUBIS"."IPYYB_KOM_BASVURUEVRAK"
  (
    PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE "USERS" PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0) ;
```

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: What exact version of Oracle are you using? Also, unless you're creating 2 objects with the same name and type, i.e. one normal and one lower case there's no need to put inverted commas around the name. You're more likely to cause yourself a world of pain by doing so than help anything - what happens if someone adds the column `"id"` to your table?

Comment: Have you tried those same two insert statements when connected to the database using SQL*Plus or a tool like TOAD or SQL*Developer? We need to isolate this to find out exactly where the problem is arising.

Comment: I'll try it on SQLDeveloper now. I don't know what TOAD is.

Comment: I tried the insert query on sqldeveloper but normally it opens a popup to get the values but now it doesnt. How can I add BLOB in insert?

Comment: I did it with sqldeveloper. It works fine with or without the sequence. Could the problem be ADO.NET?